# TypeError when trying to send outlook email via python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

I found this quick python script to send emails via the outlook app on my PC. The strange part is that I receive a TypeError when I try to run the code, but the email still sends. This is an issue because I am trying to send multiple emails that are identical, but it only sends one, then the terminal closes. My code and the terminal results are below:

```py
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')

mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'mitchell.mcdonald@veeder.com;mmcdonald1575@gmail.com'
mail.Subject = 'Sample Email'

mail.send()
```

This yields...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\Users\mitchell.McDonald\Desktop\Mitchell McDonald\Programming\Python\emailTest.py", line 10, in <module>
    mail.send()
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

Similarly, if I try the following code...

```py
import win32com.client

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')

mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'mitchell.mcdonald@veeder.com;mmcdonald1575@gmail.com'
mail.Subject = 'Sample Email'


for i in range(5):
    try:
        mail.send()

    except:
        print("failed")
```

A single Email WILL send, but I will see "failed" 5 times in the terminal. So it's almost like "mail.send()" fails every time, but somehow slips through and actually executes once.

Ideally, I would like to see 5 sent emails.

Can someone please help.

Comment: What that implies is that "send" is being handled as a property, so that just referring to the name is enough to trigger the sending, and then the property returns a boolean.  I do know the actual Outlook DOM function is `Send` with a capital S.  Is the behavior any different if you fix that?

Comment: That actually worked. I am able to send one email with no error. However, when I try to implement the for loop to send 5 emails, I am getting this...                                        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\mitchell.McDonald\Desktop\Mitchell McDonald\Programming\Python\emailTest.py", line 13, in <module>
    mail.Send()
  File "<COMObject CreateItem>", line 2, in Send
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'The item has been moved or deleted.', None, 0, -2147221238), None)

Comment: I believe I have actually been successful by creating the object itself inside the for loop for each iteration. Thank you

Comment: @TimRoberts This is one of the drawbacks of win32com.client.Dispatch(): you don't always know whether you have an early (case sensitive) or late (case insensitive) bound interface.